# JNI FindClass called with NullPointerException when AdaptiveCard.DeserializeFromString called on android

Tags: java, android, adaptive-cards

I am trying to build a lazy loaded list that shows a set of adaptive cards using adaptive cards android build 2.7.0. I was able to get the first set of data successfully parsed and rendered. But when the second set of data is fetched from the backend, the deserializer complains by throwing the following error.

**JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI FindClass called with pending exception** java.lang.NullPointerException: null upcall object in AdaptiveCards::BaseCardElementParser::Deserialize
java_vm_ext.cc:577]   at long io.adaptivecards.objectmodel.AdaptiveCardObjectModelJNI.AdaptiveCard_DeserializeFromString__SWIG_0(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, long, io.adaptivecards.objectmodel.ParseContext) (AdaptiveCardObjectModelJNI.java:-2)
java_vm_ext.cc:577]   at io.adaptivecards.objectmodel.ParseResult io.adaptivecards.objectmodel.AdaptiveCard.DeserializeFromString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, io.adaptivecards.objectmodel.ParseContext) (AdaptiveCard.java:211)
java_vm_ext.cc:577]   at io.adaptivecards.objectmodel.ParseResult com.mrg.cardfeed.PSCardLoader.deserialize(java.lang.String)

error is thrown at the following call

ParseResult parseResult = AdaptiveCard.DeserializeFromString(card, AdaptiveCardRenderer.VERSION, context);

```
// the simplified version of the method I use to render a card
 public void renderCardView(CardDO cardDO) {
        try {

            RawDO rawcard = cardDO.getRowData();
            String card = rawcard.raw_json;

            ParseResult parseResult = AdaptiveCard.DeserializeFromString(card, AdaptiveCardRenderer.VERSION, context);

            JsonObject jsonObject = JsonParser.parseString(additionalData).getAsJsonObject(); // other data
            RenderedAdaptiveCard renderedCard = AdaptiveCardRenderer.getInstance().render(activity, ((FragmentActivity) activity).getSupportFragmentManager(), parseResult.GetAdaptiveCard(), (ICardActionHandler) activity, PSHostConfig.psconfig.current);

            for (AdaptiveWarning warning : renderedCard.getWarnings()) {
                System.out.println(warning.getMessage());
            }

            View rendered = renderedCard.getView();
            rendered.canScrollVertically(1);
            
             String additionalData = parseResult.GetAdaptiveCard().GetAdditionalProperties().getString(); // for other data

// Present the view 
          

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

I am using an async task to fetch the data, parse and render the cards. So I assume the problem has something to do with thread safety. Has anyone run in to this problem with adaptive cards android.
Please let me know if I am making a rookie mistake as I am very new to adaptive cards.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake I had made was calling AdaptiveCard.DeserializeFromString() in a seperate thread. Once I moved the deserializing and rendering of the adaptivecard to the main thread, the problem was solved.